# Does acupuncture work?

Tags: medical-science, acupuncture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any evidence for acupuncture being an effective treatment?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/402/is-there-any-evidence-for-acupuncture-being-an-effective-treatment)

Here is a [link](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/?p=10254) to the article.

I have fallen for the article. And now I want to know does acupuncture work?

Comment: Flagged for review.  Please expand and cite exactly what you are skeptical about (the write-up or acupuncture).

Comment: @Larian LeQuella: Edited.

Comment: We already have one general question about acupuncture, so I'm closing this one as a duplicate. If you have a more specific question about acupuncture you can edit this question and it might get reopened. I also made the title more neutral.

Comment: define "really work". Many patients report temporary relieve from symptoms for at least some conditions (especially pain relief). This to me indicates that while it's not in itself a cure it can help make patients comfortable which in itself can help as part of a treatment regimen (mind I'm talking about the Chinese application of the technique, not the quacks calling themselves accupunturists in Europe and the US). Whether placebo or not doesn't matter here. If a patient feels pain relief, he's suffering less no matter the way it's achieved.

Comment: Here is the duplicate question:  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/402/is-there-any-evidence-for-acupuncture-being-an-effective-treatment